# Write int into file in c : getting weird character "\00"

Tags: c, int

I want to write some int into a binary file using the function write. My integers are in two "arrays", and I want to write every int into my file. My code :

```
void write_graph(int **time, int **tailles, int lenght, int thread_number) //lenth = nombre de tests pour un nombre de coeur
{
    int f, i, j;
    char tmp[16] = {0x0};
    f = open("val", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (f < 0)
    {
        perror("open in write_graph");
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
            {
                int ti = time[i][j];
                int tl = tailles[i][j];
                printf("%d %d",ti, tl);
                //sprintf(tmp, "%d %d", ti, tl);
                sprintf(tmp, "%d", ti);
                write(f, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
            }
            write(f, "\n", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, I also write the integer from **tailles, but it contains random number, and I don't have any bug with this (I simplified a bit my code). Inside my for loop, I have a printf. It displays my integer nicely. But When I open my file "val", I get this :
[image]
Here is how I initialize my array **time

```
time = malloc(thread_number * sizeof(int *));
    tailles = malloc(thread_number * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
    {
        time[i] = malloc(lenght * sizeof(int));
        tailles[i] = malloc(lenght * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
        {
            time[i][j] = j;
            tailles[i][j] = Random(1, 10);
        }
    }
```

I tried lots of different techniques, but I still get the same result... I don't know how to write a int into a file in c...
Here is what valgrind shows (I don't know how to interpret the leak summary):
[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged "binary-files"? You are trying to write a text file. Please remove the tag or clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
write(f, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

You are always writing `sizeof(tmp)` (= 16) bytes regardless of the actual length of the string.The length of the string is `strlen(tmp)`:

So this is correct:

```
write(f, tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

But anyway it's easier to use `fopen` instead of `open` and `fprintf` instead of `sprintf` followed by `write`.

The valgrind output is unrelated to this issue.